# Apache wildcard documentroot

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, documentroot

I would like to use the the subdomain as my DocumentRoot folder

```
foo.example.com
```

Goes to

```
/var/www/foo
```

However I do not want to add a new entry for every subdomain

Basically

```
*.example.com
```

Goes to

```
/var/www/*
```

Where * is any alphanum string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) should do it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName placeholdername
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
</VirtualHost>
```